# Java validation of a URL through Regular Expression

Tags: java, regex

Java validation of a URL through Regular Expression

```
    String url = "https://my-company-08.vv.xyz.com/abc.svc/Abcdef(id='{0}',text='ABC.XYZ')?$query=xxxx&$format=xml";
```

Comment: First:  **what** are you validating?  Second:  why do you think ***regex*** is a good idea for it?

Comment: Do you need us to do that regex validation? and why Regex..? Just utilise the URI methods to do that like this,   `if( (request.getRequestURI()).contains('your required character') )` and make necessary changes to if condition

Comment: i was printing the service url in logger..during veracode scan it throws flaw. so i was validating with regex and printing the log

Comment: You don't mention what "flaw" you're encountering here, though.

Answer (score 3):

URLs are potentially complex beasts with many [possible variants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator#Syntax). If you write your own regex parser you will most likely fail to cover all cases. Use the built in URI or URL class to do it for you...

```
private static boolean isValidUri(String candidate) {
    try {
        new URI(candidate);
        return true;
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

With URL

```
private static boolean isValidUrl(String candidate) {
    try {
        new URL(candidate);
        return true;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Your specific syntax errors....

```
// returns false, error at character 51 which is the first (
System.out.println(isValidUri("https://my-company-08.vv.xyz.com/abc.svc/Abcdef(id= '{sd54asds2f21sddf}',text='ABC.XYZ')?$query=myClient&$format=xml"));

// returns true without the (id= '{sd54asds2f21sddf}',text='ABC.XYZ') stuff
System.out.println(isValidUri("https://my-company-08.vv.xyz.com/abc.svc/Abcdef?$query=myClient&$format=xml"));
```

Comment: My approach is to not use regex at all as there are built in classes in Java which represent URLs, these perform validation as part of their construction and throw errors when given bad inputs - why not build upon these rather than starting from scratch.

Comment: Can you update your question with details of the RestTemplate setup and I'll investigate further...